# How to Properly Launch ConnectionSettingsTask from Live Tile

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am wondering how to implement the required functionality mandated by Microsoft's application certification process, whereby an app that loads into a certain page must automatically go back to the start screen when the hardware back button is pressed, when launching the ConnectionSettingsTask from a Secondary Live Tile.

Currently, I am performing a check in the OnNavigatedTo event of my MainPage, that if a certain tile parameter is found, load the ConnectionSettingsTask for Wifi. That works properly, but when the user presses the hardware back button, my MainPage is navigated to as opposed to the start screen. Should I place this check somewhere else in the application, and if so, where? I also have a UriMapper class that is used to implement a Welcome Page on first load, otherwise automatically navigate to the MainPage. This is called in App.xaml.cs Application Launching and Application Resuming events. Could I add this here? Any advice, information, considerations, or links would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnNavigationTo event, you can check the NavigationMode to know the type of navigation: forward or backward. This way, you can distinguish the moment when your application is launched from the tile and the moment when the user is going back to it:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            // The user is going back, exit the application?
        }
        else
        {
            // Launch the connection settings
        }
    }
```